# Как в MySQL объединять столбцы?

Tags: mysql

Нужно объединить столбец `name` и `surname` в таблице `user`.
Например, в столбце `name` значение "Иван".
А в столбце `surname` "Иванов".
А нужно, чтобы в одном столбце `name` было "Иван Иванов".

На скрине есть структура таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Объединить физически, или в выборке?

Comment: @LEQADA в mysql новичок, не понимаю, что спросили

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример того, что должно в результате получиться?

Comment: вам во время выборки надо их объединить? тогда можно использовать [`concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) или [`concat_ws`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws). Например, `select concat(name, ' ', surname) from user` или `select concat_ws(' ', name, surname) from user`. Если в базе и чтобы так и осталось, то ответ дали (правда, не понял, почему его заминосовали)

Comment: "Иван и Иванов" должно содержаться в новой таблице? Зачем вам нужно это делать?

Comment: @LEQADA Смотрите, Есть имя Иван(в рядке name) И есть фамилия(Иванов в рядке surname) мне нужно, чтоб в рядке name Получилось вот так Иван Иванов

Comment: @Merlin, ответ ниже вам не помог?

Comment: @LEQADA нет, рядок name стал иметь значение 0

Comment: @Merlin, попробуйте в ответе вместо `name + ' ' + surname;` сделать `concat_ws(' ', name, surname)`, складываются числа, а не строки, потому и 0

Comment: @BOPOH, вот почему его заминусовали :)

Comment: @LEQADA спасибо большое, помогли :3

Comment: @Merlin, так это ж, BOPOH вам помог )

Answer (score 1):

увеличить размер типа varchar

```
alter table users alter column name varchar(125);
```

проапдейтить данные

```
update users set name = name + ' ' + surname;
```

удалить колонку surname

```
alter table users drop column surname;
```

Comment: складываются числа, а не строки, строки надо объединять; исправьте на `concat` или `concat_ws`, а то ваш ответ только из-за этого и не верен